# Кодировка в phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, кодировка, phpmyadmin

Как в phpMyAdmin сделать, чтобы в полях отображались русские символы, если кодировка во всех файлах utf=8?

Вроде к тому полю надо добавить ut8-8slovenian?

Comment: utf8-general-ci - это нечувствительный к регистру utf8
utf8-general-cs - это чувствительный к регистру utf8

slovenian - точно не то, что нужно

Comment: везде поставил ее в Бд, таблице, поле. Все равно не отображает

Answer (score 1):

а здесь выставлено в utf8 ?

[image]

Comment: да  там сделал)